# Regex to read log

Tags: magento2, regex

Still struggling with that regex to read logs

This is the regex I made so far

`/^(?<date>(\[|)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(T| )\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\]|.+\d{2}:\d{2}\]|.+\d{2}:\d{2})))(?<message>.*?)$/gm`

If we take the following text as sample

```
[2022-10-31 10:16:22] main.ERROR: The "--only-trace" option does not exist.
#0 /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(143): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->addLongOption('only-trace', 'test')
#1 /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(79): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parseLongOption('--only-trace=te...')
#2 /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php(55): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parse()
[2022-10-31 10:16:22] main.ERROR: I'm a new group
```

I'm expecting to retrieve the 2 dates with the full text. Sadly i'm only getting the first line

[image]

Do i have the wrong approach ? How can i fix it to make it work on multiline ?

Basically, the date is the one that should define a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using : Worked for me
preg_match_all('/(?<date>\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}])(?<message>.+?)(\[\])/', $fileSubContent, $contents);


Here is the syntax : preg_match_all(pattern, input, matches, flags, offset)
```

Comment: This is your regex, doesn't seems to work : https://regex101.com/r/oBXtVJ/1 Here is mine : https://regex101.com/r/tevAsZ/1